# Switch to web iframe and fill drop-downs using excel vba

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, iframe

I have below code which opens web page, calls java-script function. What next I want is:
Switch to iframe named `displayFrame`. Then select options in drop-downs. Currently I am unable switch to iframe and add values in form. I am new to this, so need your help.

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Fillform()
Dim URL As String
Dim ie, frm As Object
Dim FF As Integer
Dim wb As WebBrowser
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim button, goBtn As Object
Dim HTML As HTMLDocument
Dim Dropdown As IHTMLElement
Dim dropOption As IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Dim link As HTMLLinkElement
Dim theFrame As HTMLIFrame
Dim Frame1, Frame2 As HTMLIFrame

On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

URL = "https://webtac.industrysoftware.automation.siemens.com/webpr/webpr.php?objtype=frames&g_userid=a3rgcw&g_session_id=7302840" 'for TEST

Set ie = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate URL

Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop
' Call java-script function
ie.Navigate ("javascript:parent.gotoCreate('advanced');")

Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop

Set theFrame = HTMLdoc.frames(0)
Set HTML = ie.Document

ie.Document.all.Item("product_application").Value = "NX"
ie.Document.getElementById("textInputField").Value = "N/A"

Set Dropdown = HTML.getElementById("product_application")

    For Each dropOption In Dropdown.getElementsByTagName("option")
        If dropOption.innerText = "Design" Then
            Dropdown.Value = dropOption.Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next dropOption

' or may be this way to select drop-down
ie.Document.getElementById("priority_selection").Value = "Design"
```

Iframe html code:

`<frame name="displayFrame" src="/webpr/webpr.php?objtype=MyWebPR&amp;g_userid=a3rgcw&amp;g_session_id=7321635&amp;g_devmode=&amp;g_dbname=">`

Comment: Cross post: https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/switch-to-web-iframe-and-fill-drop-downs-using-excel-vba.36703/

Comment: Are you sure the information you have provided above is sufficient for someone else to provide you with any solution? As it's an iframe issue, pseudo solution may not be of much help for you.

Comment: @Shahin, I am not sure of it.

Comment: Okay, you didn't understand what i meant. Anyways, here is the solution:`dim frm as object
Set frm = HTML.getElementsByName("displayFrame")(0).contentWindow.document`. Make use of it yourself.

Comment: Trying but same error: `Object variable or With block variable not set` at above line.

Comment: That is what i meant in the first place. It's hard to provide any solution hypothetically when it comes to fix the `iframe` issues. That webpage requires log-in so this the the best you can get.

Comment: I see. Anyway I will keep trying. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This URL  is not valid for testing in that there is a login to get past. Is there a valid one to use?

Answer (score 0):

Tips of how to get IFrame document- try to follow this logic **(not tested)**:

```
'for early binding
Dim IEApp As InternetExplorer
Set IEApp = New InternetExplorer

Dim docHTML As HTMLDocument
Set docHTML = IEApp.document

Dim webIFrame As Object 'As HTMLIFrame

'try with any of this lines to get to IFrame
Set webIFrame = docHTML.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0) 'your index if not 0
Set webIFrame = = docHTML.frames(0)

'and to get to document:
Dim docIFrameHTML As HTMLDocument
set docIFrameHTML = webIFrame.document

'next you could try to fill your forms...
```

Comment: I added code till javafunction at above then, posted your code after that. But getting error "Object variable or With block variable not set"  at `Set webIFrame = docHTML.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0) 'your index if not 0
Set webIFrame = docHTML.frames(0)` If I add code (after java-script call) to wait for page load then it seems that macro is not going ahead of that though page is loaded.